# Python nested generators

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I was trying to implement the reverse function of itertools.izip on Python 2.7.1. The thing is that I find a problem, and I don't have an explantion. 
Solution 1, iunzip_v1 works perfectly. But solution 2. iunzip_v2, doesn't works as expected. Til now, I haven't found any relevant information about this problem, and reading the PEP about generators, it sound it should work, but it doesn't.

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

def iunzip_v1(iterable):
    _tmp, iterable = itertools.tee(iterable, 2)
    iters = itertools.tee(iterable, len(_tmp.next()))
    return tuple(itertools.imap(itemgetter(i), it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))

def iunzip_v2(iterable):
    _tmp, iterable = itertools.tee(iterable, 2)
    iters = itertools.tee(iterable, len(_tmp.next()))
    return tuple((elem[i] for elem in it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))
```

result:

```
In [17]: l
Out[17]: [(0, 0, 0), (1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 6), (3, 6, 9), (4, 8, 12)]

In [18]: map(list, iunzip.iunzip_v1(l))
Out[18]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]]

In [19]: map(list, iunzip.iunzip_v2(l))
Out[19]: [[0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Seems that iunzip_v2 is using the last value, so the generators aren't keeping the value while they are created inside the first generator.
I'm missing something and I don't know what is.

Thanks in advance if something can clarify me this situation.

**UPDATE:** 
I've found the explanation here [PEP-289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding), my first read was at PEP-255.
The solution I'm trying to implement is a lazy one, so:

```
  zip(*iter) or izip(*...)
```

doesn't work for me, because *arg expand the argument list.

Comment: `zip` has to expand the argument list. The first element `zip` returns is the first element of each input argument. So it has iterated over the entire argument list. What you are doing with `tee` is creating a lot of copies of the input list.

Comment: First, @Andrés, don't call `tuple` at the end if you want a lazy implementation.

Comment: Second, @Jochen, Andrés' current implementation, if it didn't call `tuple`, would be lazy in the _argument generator_, but not in the _arguments_, which have a `len` and are therefore sequences.

Comment: Third, @Jochen, @Andrés, you can have an `izip` function that is lazy in the argument generator, or in the individual arguments, but not both.

Comment: @senderle: you're right, I can have both. My idea was to be lazy at the iunzip argument iterator, I am assuming that the tuples inside the argument generator aren't bigger.
Thanks for your replies!

Comment: @Jochen, sorry, looking back over this I think I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel in a crazy way. `izip` is its own inverse:

```
>>> list(izip(*izip(range(10), range(10))))
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

But that doesn't quite answer your question, does it?

The problem with your nested generators is a scoping problem that happens because the innermost generators don't get used until the outermost generator has already run:

```
def iunzip_v2(iterable):
    _tmp, iterable = itertools.tee(iterable, 2)
    iters = itertools.tee(iterable, len(_tmp.next()))
    return tuple((elem[i] for elem in it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))
```

Here, you generate three generators, each of which uses *the same variable*, `i`. Copies of this variable are not made. Then, `tuple` exhausts the outermost generator, creating a tuple of generators:

```
>>> iunzip_v2((range(3), range(3)))
(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d4a50>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d4aa0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d4af0>)
```

At this point, each of these generators will execute `elem[i]` for each element of `it`. And since `i` is now equal to 3 for all three generators, you get the last element each time.

The reason the first version works is that `itemgetter(i)` is a closure, with its own scope -- so every time it returns a function, it generates a new scope, within which the value of `i` does not change.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks to answer! 
The problem with your first solution is that izip(*izip(...)), the * expand the iterators before they will be used, and that is what I want to avoid. When I asked the question I read the PEP-255 "Simple generators", but the answer was on PEP-289 "Generator expressions" I've found this [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding]. As you said my confusion is with the evaluation and execution order. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @Andrés, so what I understand you to be saying is that you want not an "`iunzip`", but an `izip` that unpacks an argument generator lazily, given that the elements in the generator are already sequences. That works, but as I say above, don't call `tuple` at the end in that case.

Comment: as I replied above, I am assuming the tuples of the argument iterator aren't bigger, so in this case, I call tuple with that "precondition".

Comment: @Andrés, ok, I think I misunderstood your intent. My point was just that you could be a little lazier with `return ((elem[i] for elem in it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))`. But also, note that @Jochen is right in the sense that once the first generator in the tuple returned by iunzip_v1 is used up, the remaining generators are no longer really "lazy." As the [tee docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) say, "This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage."

Answer (score 5):

Ok this is a bit tricky. When you use a name like `i` the value it stands for is looked up just during runtime. In this code:

```
return tuple((elem[i] for elem in it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))
```

you return a number of generators, `(elem[i] for elem in it)` and each of them uses the same name `i`. When the function returns, the loop in `tuple( .. for i in ..  )` has ended and `i` has been set to it's final value (`3` in your example). Once you evaluate these generators to lists, they all create the same values because they are using the same `i`.

Btw:

```
unzip = lambda zipped: zip(*zipped)
```

Comment: Hi Jochen, thanks for your reply. I left a comment here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432782/python-nested-generators/6432907#6432907] that explain what I've found and my confussion. Thanks again